# How to place microsecond delay in kernel?

Tags: c, tcp, linux-kernel

I want to place microsecond delay in `Linux kernel`. Which functions supports it and what header file to be added for it?

Comment: It depends on context, in any case the mentioned documentation is what you have to read.

Answer (score 1):

It's better for you to read `Documentation/timers/timers-howto.txt` in linux kernel source code.

In brief, you can use `msleep(unsigned long msecs)` whose header is `linux/delay.h`

Comment: I tried msleep() it's working but i want to put microsecond delay. usleep() is not working

Comment: Use `usleep_range(unsigned long min, unsigned long max)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

short sleeps are done by busy looping. they are to be discouraged.
use udelay() but for no more than 1000 microseconds.

```
#include <linux/delay.h>
void udelay(unsigned long usecs);
```

Comment: `udelay()` gives error. "Undefined symbol: __const_udelay". What I can understand is `msleep` uses `udelay` only. `udelay` calls the ultimate `__udelay`. But if I want to put the `udelay` in `net` directory of linux kernel, what should be the proper header file to include?

Comment: @RatDon [msleep](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timer.c#L1675) really stops
the kernel thread, whereas usleep does a busy loop. They are not connected.
Sorry, I dont know why you have an undefined. It depends on your architecture. For x86
it is exported from [arch/x86/lib/delay.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/lib/delay.c#L127). As said by Arthur in another answer you can use [usleep_range](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timer.c#L1715) which uses high-resolution timers.